# Insert Statement in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

what data do I have to enter for datatype datetime in SQL server when using an INSERT statement

Comment: you have to enter date time or cast the string to datetime. btw please provide more details about your question

Comment: What are you using to insert the data?

Comment: you shouldn't have to specify a datatype in an insert statement in SQL

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you're trying to insert the current date and time, try inserting `GETDATE()`.

Comment: A simple google search returns the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enter data in ISO format i.e.

```
insert into table (datecolumn) values ('2012-04-22 13:23:12')
```

Answer (score 5):

Example:

```
INSERT YourTable (YourDateTimeField)
VALUES ('2012-04-27T08:35:00')
```

Supply a value in a format that can be safely implicitly converted to a DATETIME without risk of misinterpration due to regional settings. So, per this example, the yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss format is a good way to go.

Reference: [ISO 8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

DATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS